# Graph nodes coming reversed when copied

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to extract the matching nodes along with their direction from the graph. The code is given below:

```
for n1,n2,attr in G_new.edges(data=True):
            if G_source.has_edge(n1,n2) :
                #Get the specific weight between the two nodes
                w = G_source[n1][n2]['weight']
                matching_graph.add_edge(n1,n2,weight=w)
                matching_graph.node[n1]['order'] = G_new.node[n1]['order']
                matching_graph.node[n2]['order'] = G_new.node[n2]['order']
                print('Matching:', n1,'->',n2,'order:',matching_graph.node[n1]['order'],'->',matching_graph.node[n2]['order'],'weight:',w)

        graphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(matching_graph))

        mcs_length = 0
        mcs_graph = nx.Graph()
        for i, graph in enumerate(graphs):
            print('i:',i)
            if len(graph.nodes()) > mcs_length:
                mcs_length = len(graph.nodes())
                mcs_graph = graph.copy()

        total_weight=0
        for n1,n2,attr in mcs_graph.edges(data=True):
            w = mcs_graph[n1][n2]['weight']
            total_weight=total_weight+w
            print(n1,'->',n2,'order:',mcs_graph.node[n1]['order'],'->',mcs_graph.node[n2]['order'],'weight:',w,'total weight:', total_weight)
        print("***printing MCS***")
        self.printGraphTable(mcs_graph)
```

The sentence I am passing is:

```
fan would have a hard time sit through this one .
```

When I do a print in the first graph I am getting the following which is correct:

```
Matching: hard -> time order: 4 -> 5 weight: 1
Matching: have -> a order: 2 -> 3 weight: 1
Matching: would -> have order: 1 -> 2 weight: 1
Matching: a -> hard order: 3 -> 4 weight: 1
```

However, when I look at the graph created from the copied nodes and edges I am getting:

```
hard -> time order: 4 -> 5 weight: 1 total weight: 1
hard -> a order: 4 -> 3 weight: 1 total weight: 2
a -> have order: 3 -> 2 weight: 1 total weight: 3
have -> would order: 2 -> 1 weight: 1 total weight: 4
```

Here we see that the direction of the last three nodes has got reversed. I am understanding why this is happening. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a Graph object rather than a DiGraph object and so the issue.

```
return_mcs_graph = nx.DiGraph()
for i, graph in enumerate(graphs):
    if len(graph.nodes()) > mcs_length:
        mcs_length = len(graph.nodes())
        mcs_graph = graph.copy()

total_weight=0
for n1,n2,attr in mcs_graph.edges(data=True):
    w = mcs_graph[n1][n2]['weight']

    if G_new.has_edge(n1,n2):
        return_mcs_graph.add_edge(n1,n2,weight=w)
    elif G_new.has_edge(n2,n1):
        return_mcs_graph.add_edge(n2,n1,weight=w)
    return_mcs_graph.node[n1]['order'] = G_new.node[n1]['order']
    return_mcs_graph.node[n2]['order'] = G_new.node[n2]['order']
    total_weight=total_weight+w
print("***printing return_mcs_graph***")
self.printGraphTable(return_mcs_graph)
print(total_weight)
```